# Finding distinct count of combination of columns values in sql

Tags: sql

Currently I have a table this :

```
Roll no.   Names
------------------
  1        Sam
  1        Sam 
  2        Sasha 
  2        Sasha 
  3        Joe
  4        Jack 
  5        Jack 
  5        Julie
```

I want to write a query in which I get count of the combination in another column

Required output

```
Combination    distinct count 
-----------------------------
2-Sasha             1
5-Jack              1
5-Julie             1
```

Comment: select concat(Rollno,'-',Names) as combination, count(*) as total from table group by rollno,names

Comment: How is the `1` calculated?  It seems superfluous.  And where is `'1-Sam'`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you could group by these columns and use a `count` function:

```sql
SELECT   rollno, name, COUNT(*)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY rollno, name
```

You could also concat the two columns:

```sql
SELECT   CONCAT(rollno, '-', name), COUNT(*)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY CONCAT(rollno, '-', name)
```